# Add a date stamp to stdout from a Java program

Tags: java, bash, service

I have an service that runs at boot time that starts a shell script that starts a java program.  The stdout/stderr from the program is dumped to a log file, typically this ends up just being runtime exceptions.  The problem is, however, while it works to log the exceptions to the log file, it doesn't have any kind of date stamp to let me know when that exemption happened.

nohup /my/program/start.sh >> /my/log.lg 2>&1&

How can I capture the exceptions and log them with a time/date stamp?

Comment: Can you edit `/my/program/start.sh`? How is it doing the logging? What do you mean by "exceptions"? Try to follow the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post.

Comment: Is "exemption" a typo for 'exception'?

Answer (score 1):

## `System.out` & `System.err`

Java supports both [`stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) & [`stderr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) via the [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class as a pair of [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) objects already instantiated for your convenience.

- [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)
- [`System.err`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err)

Example:

```
System.out.println( "Bonjour tous le monde." ) ;
System.err.println( "Oops, a tear in the fabric of space-time has occurred." ) ;
```

If your expected output failed to appear, check your Java code. Perhaps a [logging framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework) has been used to divert such output.

## `Instant`

> …and log them with a time/date stamp

As for a timestamp, generally best to do all your logging in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) rather than a particular time zone. Use the  `Instant` class.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). The current moment may be captured in milliseconds or microseconds rather than nanoseconds, depending on your implementation of Java and the limitations of your host OS and hardware.

By default, [`Instant::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString()) generates a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format such as `2018-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z`.

```
System.out.println( "Current moment is: " + Instant.now().toString() ) ;
System.err.println( "Oops, error occurred at: " + Instant.now() ) ;
```

## Logging exceptions

> How can I capture the exceptions…

Study the [Oracle Tutorial on exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html), specifically the section, [*Catching and Handling Exceptions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

Wrap the code where an exception might be thrown with a `try-catch`.

```
try {
    …
} catch (ExceptionType name) {
    …
} catch (ExceptionType name) {
    …
}
```

Example from the Tutorial.

```
try {
    …

} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException name) {
    System.err.println( "IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage() );

} catch (IOException name) {
    System.err.println( "Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage() );

}
```

Insert your timestamps as desired.

```
try {
    …

} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException name) {
    System.err.println( "Caught IndexOutOfBoundsException at " + Instant.now() + ": " + e.getMessage() );

} catch (IOException name) {
    System.err.println( "Caught IOException at " + Instant.now() + ": " + e.getMessage() );

}
```

## Logging framework

Eventually, you may choose to handle all such progress & error reporting through a [logging framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework). You can direct your output through any combination of destinations including standard streams, local log files, pagers/[SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS), and remote logging services.

I suggest using the [*slf4j*](https://www.slf4j.org) façade. You can plug already-used legacy logging tools into slf4j via adapters, or for [greenfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenfield_project#Software_development) work use the direct implementation of slf4j, [*Logback*](https://logback.qos.ch).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).